# How can I execute a function with boosts io_service.post() and use an array or pointer as parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

While trying to construct a program, which can transmit a block/array of data with boosts `async_write`, I probably ran into trouble with my threads:

This is what I would like to execute:

```
write(unsigned char *pMsg, unsigned short nMsgLen){
      io_service_.post(boost::bind(&m_client::write_buf, this, pMsg, nMsgLen));
}

write_buf(unsigned char *pMsg, unsigned short nMsgLen){

          boost::asio::async_write(target,
                            boost::asio::buffer(pMsg, nMsgLen),
                            boost::bind(&m_client::write_buf_compl,
                            this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

It does compile, but `pMsg` has not the right content, when `write_buf` is called, and I think it is because it is called not inside of the same thread.

So, how could I adjust this construct to transfer my array as a parameter?!

Comment: you have to be sure that a buffer pointed by `pMsg` will alive when `write_buf()` gets called. In other words: if that buffer is smth local to caller of `write()` you'll be in troubles if that function will exit (and variable holding the buffer gets out of scope)

Comment: Why this question is tagged boost-thread?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you pretty much understand where your problem is. The quick fix for it would be to pass that buffer by copying its content:

```
void write(unsigned char *pMsg, unsigned short nMsgLen) {
    // TODO: Take care of exception safety...
    char *pMsgCopy = (char *)malloc(nMsgLen);
    memcpy(pMsgCopy, pMsg, nMsgLen);
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&m_client::write_buf, this,
                                 pMsgCopy, nMsgLen));
}

void write_buf(unsigned char *pMsg, unsigned short nMsgLen)
{
    // Achtung! Don't forget to free memory in complection callback.
    boost::asio::async_write(target,
                             boost::asio::buffer(pMsg, nMsgLen),
                             boost::bind(&m_client::write_buf_compl,
                                         this,
                                         boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void write_buf_compl(...)
{
    free(pMsg);
}
```

If you are crazy about efficiency then you can avoid copy by having the caller of `write()` provide dynamically allocated buffer in a first place. But if you are, actually, crazy about performance, then I'd recommend not to use Boost.ASIO. But that is another story.

Comment: better to use some kind of a smart pointer instead of raw one. like `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` at least if C++11 is not allowed